# Is it possible, that the momentum chrome addon influences the css of loaded websites?

Tags: momentum

When I opened up my website I noticed that the css was not loaded correctly.
I tried to reload the cache but nothing changed.
When I disabled the momentum chrome addon my website loaded correctly.